# css style tag not working

Tags: html, css

when i add this code to my css file it does not work ? However when i add this to my jsp file in the Head tag it works ?

Any idea what am i missing ?

```
  <style>
    input[type="text"]
            {
     width:500px;
     display:block;
     margin-bottom:10px;
     background-color:yellow;
            }

    input[type="button"]
            {
        width:200px;
        margin-left:35px;   
        display:block;
            }
    </style>
```

Comment: Are you putting the `<style>` tags in your CSS file? That will cause the CSS to not parse properly

Comment: Remove the style tags when you add it to the css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<style> </style>` tags .Not required for external CSS.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the style open and close in external style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

The `style` tags tell the browser how to treat the contents when included directly within your page and are necessary because of the potential for mixed content types within a single html document.

However when you are defining styles directly within a CSS file you should not include the style tags as the contents are determined by the file type (i.e. an external style sheet).

Your CSS contents should look as follows:

```
input[type="text"]
{
   width:500px;
   display:block;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   background-color:yellow;
}

input[type="button"]
{
   width:200px;
   margin-left:35px;   
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an external CSS file then you should not use `<style>` tags. Use style tags only when your using the CSS in the same HTML document